# Can't log in when trying to integrate omniauth facebook with rails and deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to implement omniauth facebook for an application I am deploying to heroku.

I get the following message:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application
>   owner check the logs for more information.

When clicking over:

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %><br />
  <% end %>
```

In /config/devise.rb I Have:

```
  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  config.omniauth :facebook, '***', '***', 
  scope: 'email',
  info_fields: 'email',
  secure_image_url: true,
  image_size: 'large',
  token_params: { parse: :json },
  callback_url: 'https://pentalingo.herokuapp.com/users/auth/facebook/callback'
```

and these are the logs:

```
 dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=33ms status=302 bytes=1197 protocol=https
2019-10-04T16:52:08.641707+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:08.641611 #4]  INFO -- : [fcfdf06f-ac86-403e-b3e8-0630204bd5e6] Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 46.24.93.212 at 2019-10-04 16:52:08 +0000
2019-10-04T16:52:08.642218+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:08.642144 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
2019-10-04T16:52:09.301754+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:09.301658 #4]  INFO -- : [3971d9a5-d629-4e86-a0a1-157dfdc396c6] Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 46.24.93.212 at 2019-10-04 16:52:09 +0000
2019-10-04T16:52:09.302090+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:09.302037 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
2019-10-04T16:52:09.302778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/auth/facebook" host=pentalingo.herokuapp.com request_id=3971d9a5-d629-4e86-a0a1-157dfdc396c6 fwd="46.24.93.212" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=1197 protocol=https
2019-10-04T16:52:10.220974+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.220880 #4]  INFO -- : [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6] Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQDSIo5-TFkKDII-ncfdoy0sJe2K2zXK5Gzlr6b0hQjpzKwcaKqGXPC10QMiSCpM4bU0FvcImY9ZFG5OJO3snOEgLC209DWBqIrNBbVCeiXj6kFrnRhBcMFP4mlbSleeuH2OutMN1cPIPSWFLorrOHp6BxcbABOh88NB9A12_iGxcVIUPj-hJWDm75xgEMv80sJqaEh_EHzgMFn2urP1QE8bG9lWRxvOX20BuLWrcJuIEcHIBtEH4TSyxjeaRM_6qmlvbRObxTZJ1MY-T7edOI3BfzXnF4oqPBBSpZRPtUcXjG48ZHN_lQMo36Ua86vodsi38ibWWPdj3JBzLuo9ajZV&state=0d915222bc5a9fd101bf721f12f2ce011f305a62c046e8ae" for 46.24.93.212 at 2019-10-04 16:52:10 +0000
2019-10-04T16:52:10.221356+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.221262 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
2019-10-04T16:52:10.545775+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.545487 #4]  INFO -- : [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6] Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
2019-10-04T16:52:10.545796+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.545595 #4]  INFO -- : [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6]   Parameters: {"code"=>"AQDSIo5-TFkKDII-ncfdoy0sJe2K2zXK5Gzlr6b0hQjpzKwcaKqGXPC10QMiSCpM4bU0FvcImY9ZFG5OJO3snOEgLC209DWBqIrNBbVCeiXj6kFrnRhBcMFP4mlbSleeuH2OutMN1cPIPSWFLorrOHp6BxcbABOh88NB9A12_iGxcVIUPj-hJWDm75xgEMv80sJqaEh_EHzgMFn2urP1QE8bG9lWRxvOX20BuLWrcJuIEcHIBtEH4TSyxjeaRM_6qmlvbRObxTZJ1MY-T7edOI3BfzXnF4oqPBBSpZRPtUcXjG48ZHN_lQMo36Ua86vodsi38ibWWPdj3JBzLuo9ajZV", "state"=>"0d915222bc5a9fd101bf721f12f2ce011f305a62c046e8ae"}
2019-10-04T16:52:10.552444+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.552371 #4]  INFO -- : [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
2019-10-04T16:52:10.553072+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.553001 #4] FATAL -- : [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6]
2019-10-04T16:52:10.553136+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.553075 #4] FATAL -- : [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.provider does not exist
2019-10-04T16:52:10.553140+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1...
2019-10-04T16:52:10.553143+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-10-04T16:52:10.553145+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $3):
2019-10-04T16:52:10.553167+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.553124 #4] FATAL -- : [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6]
2019-10-04T16:52:10.553254+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-10-04T16:52:10.553182 #4] FATAL -- : [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6] app/models/user.rb:54:in `from_omniauth'
2019-10-04T16:52:10.553256+00:00 app[web.1]: [41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6] app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:3:in `facebook'
2019-10-04T16:52:10.552780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQDSIo5-TFkKDII-ncfdoy0sJe2K2zXK5Gzlr6b0hQjpzKwcaKqGXPC10QMiSCpM4bU0FvcImY9ZFG5OJO3snOEgLC209DWBqIrNBbVCeiXj6kFrnRhBcMFP4mlbSleeuH2OutMN1cPIPSWFLorrOHp6BxcbABOh88NB9A12_iGxcVIUPj-hJWDm75xgEMv80sJqaEh_EHzgMFn2urP1QE8bG9lWRxvOX20BuLWrcJuIEcHIBtEH4TSyxjeaRM_6qmlvbRObxTZJ1MY-T7edOI3BfzXnF4oqPBBSpZRPtUcXjG48ZHN_lQMo36Ua86vodsi38ibWWPdj3JBzLuo9ajZV&state=0d915222bc5a9fd101bf721f12f2ce011f305a62c046e8ae" host=pentalingo.herokuapp.com request_id=41fa5c92-4e10-4e90-962e-28265bb4dfc6 fwd="46.24.93.212" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=335ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

I have already added the callback link to Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in developers.facebook

```
https://pentalingo.herokuapp.com/users/auth/facebook/callback
```

The methods in my models/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

in my users model I have:

```
  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.provider does not exist`

Looks like you need to add a `provider` column to your User model.

Comment: I have checked it, but the provider is in the user model. I did add uid, provider and image from the beggining.

Comment: The error says that it is not on the user table, that error wouldn't say the column doesn't exist if it did exist.  Are you checking in the Heroku console, or locally?  Maybe the migrations didn't run on the server.

Comment: I think that was the case, the migrations were not running on the server so I restarted everything and this time it worked (kinda). Thanks for your help.